# Booting from an ISO image using PowerCLI scripts

Tags: powershell, virtualization, vmware, virtual-machine, powercli

How do I make the following script work? Currently I am able to create a new virtual machine in my server. I wish to also load the Windows ISO image and do an unattended installation in the virtual machine. How shall I edit the script to make this work?

```
# Virtual Center Details
$server_address = "xxxxx"
$username = "xxxxx"
$password = "xxxxx"
$iso = "WINXP_X86_SP3_CD.ISO"

Get-VIServer -Server $server_address -Protocol https -User $username -Password $password

foreach ($vmm in $array)
{
    $vmm = "VirtualMachine"

    New-VM -name $vmm -DiskMB 20000 -memoryMB 2000
    Get-VM $vmm | Get-CDDrive | Set-CDDrive -IsoPath $iso -StartConnected $true -Confirm:$false
    $value = "5000"
    $vm = Get-VM $vmname | Get-View
    $vmConfigSpec = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineConfigSpec
    $vmConfigSpec.BootOptions = New-Object VMware.Vim.VirtualMachineBootOptions
    $vmConfigSpec.BootOptions.BootDelay = $value
    $vm.ReconfigVM_Task($vmConfigSpec)

    Start-vm -vm $vmname
}
```

Comment: mmm, where `$array` comes from? Why `Get-VIServer`? Did you mean `Connect-VIServer`? Which problems are you encountering with your script?

Comment: @empo yes it is get-viserver because of the version of the powercli. There is a slight change in the commands. The rest I just copied and paste it. btw my issue is with the ISO PATH image. I am getting the error "Invalid datastore format" when i run the script using the powercli command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **my issue is with the ISO PATH image. I am getting the error "Invalid datastore format"**

You are specifying isopath using `IsoPath` parameter, which is the *datastore path* to the ISO, not simply the ISO name. From your code you are not indicating any datastore.

The syntax for a datastore path is:

```
"[yourdatastore] IsoFolder\$iso"
```

Example got from PowerCLI reference online:

```
$cd = New-CDDrive -VM $vm -ISOPath "[sof-20666-esx:storage1] ISO\testISO.iso"
Set-CDDrive -CD $cd -StartConnected -Connected
```

Comment: @empo how do you check -ISOPath "[sof-20666-esx:storage1] what datastore am I using? I am currently using vSphere Client Version 4.1.0 and VMware ESXI Version 4.1.0. I connect to my server using this.

Comment: @empo thanks, it manages to read the cd rom and the iso image. but how do you use the powercli scripts to activate the Device Status (connected and connect at power on) then only the operating system will install.

Comment: I've slitghtely modified the example to include activation of Device Status as you have asked for. Hope it helps.

Comment: @empo you have been a great help. thank you so much. but can i ask you another question here itself. i have already posted the question but i feel you seem to be the right person to direct this question to.

Comment: @empo I have the following error installing my operating system in my virtual machine when I run it using VMware vSphere client. I created an automation PowerCLI scripts and it is able run the script and create the virtual machine linking with the ISO image. I managed to load the ISO image using the

Comment: New-CDDrive -VM $vm -ISOPath "[datastore1] ISO/WINXP_X86_SP3_CD.ISO" -StartConnected:$true -Confirm:$false

Comment: @ empo *"Setup did not find any hard disk drives installed in your computer. Make sure any hard disk drives are powered on and properly connected to your computer, and that any disk-related hardware configuration is correct. This may involve running a manufacturer-supplied diagnostic or setup program. Setup cannot continue. To quit Setup, press F3"*

Comment: @user: please, next time think of placing a _simple_ link to your original question. I'll have a look. Cheers